# Cannot convert value of type '[UITableViewCell.Type]' to '[_.Type]' in Swift 4.2

Tags: arrays, swift, swift4.2

Well, today after I update Xcode to version 10.0, I faced following error in my code.

```
// error: Cannot convert value of type '[UITableViewCell.Type]' to expected argument type
// '[_.Type]'  
table.registerCells(cells: [MainMenuTableViewCell.self,
                            RescueServicesTableViewCell.self])
```

Here is the `registerCells` function:

```
func registerCells<T> (cells : [T.Type]) where T: UITableViewCell  {
        for cell in cells  {
            let nib = UINib(nibName: String(describing: cell), bundle: nil)
            register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: String(describing: cell))
        }
    }
```

At the beginning I thought it might be swift re-versioning issue so I convert from swift 3 to swift 4 and after 2 hours spending time to fix syntaxes the error was still there, until I did the magic trick.

```
let cellItems = [MainMenuTableViewCell.self,
                 RescueServicesTableViewCell.self]

table.registerCells(cells:cellItems)
```

This solution works and error gone. Now my question is why I'm getting this error is this Xcode problem or I did something wrong?

Comment: Try clean build

Comment: Already tried it, not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an interesting bug ([SR-8825](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-8825)) where the compiler appears to be unable to perform type joining (the process of inferring a common supertype for a collection of types) within a member access on an implicitly unwrapped optional (IUO) declaration (presumably in your case `table` is an IUO `@IBOutlet`).

A minimal example would be:

```
class C {}
class D : C {}
class E : C {}

struct X {
  func foo<T>(_: [T.Type]) where T : C {}
}

var x: X!

// error: Cannot convert value of type '[C.Type]' to expected argument type '[_.Type]'
x.foo([D.self, E.self])
```

Making `x` either non-optional, or a strong optional (i.e `X?`) while performing either optional chaining (i.e `x?.foo`) or force unwrapping (i.e `x!.foo`) to perform the member access allows the code to compile.

---

There are a few workarounds you can use, first of which is to explicitly specify the array type, saving the compiler from having to infer the type join:

```
x.foo([D.self, E.self] as [C.Type])
```

In your case, this translates to:

```
table.registerCells(cells: 
  [MainMenuTableViewCell.self, RescueServicesTableViewCell.self] as [UITableViewCell.Type]
)
```

---

Second workaround is to use a non-optional base. In your case, you can force unwrap the IUO into a local variable before performing the member access:

```
// this is just explicitly doing what the compiler would have otherwise done implicitly.
let table = self.table!
table.registerCells(cells: [MainMenuTableViewCell.self, RescueServicesTableViewCell.self])
```

---

Third workaround is, as you've already discovered, to separate out the array into its own expression – which allows the compiler to do the type joining on its own:

```
let cellItems = [MainMenuTableViewCell.self, RescueServicesTableViewCell.self]
table.registerCells(cells: cellItems)
```

---

Though the solution I would go with in your case is to make `registerCells(cells:)` non-generic, as it doesn't appear that you're using the generic placeholder `T` for anything useful:

```
extension UITableView {
  func registerCells(_ cells: [UITableViewCell.Type]) {
    for cell in cells  {
      let nib = UINib(nibName: String(describing: cell), bundle: nil)
      register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: String(describing: cell))
    }
  }
}
```

Which you can now just call like so:

```
table.registerCells([MainMenuTableViewCell.self, RescueServicesTableViewCell.self])
```

Comment: Thank you for complete explanation on this, now it make a lot more sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: YoursCell.self), for: indexPath)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.